# Get the Top Four Value from data table . Then swap on condition

Tags: mysql, sql, database, qtp

using this command i can get TOP four values but some of the values are duplicate . so then wanted to swap based on serial number of table . using this bellow command to get the top four values now i want to swap any logic.

```
INPUT
         SN Set name  columname
          1  100 Randy 25
          2  100 many  22
          3  100 sanny 22
          4  100 nanny 35
Output
        SN Set name  columname
        2  100 many  22
        3  100 sanny 22
        1  100 Randy 25
        4  100 nanny 35

select top 4 * from filename where Set=100 order by columname DESC
```

Sort it based on column name then swap it based on serial number.

Comment: What do you mean by "swap"? Your output doesn't really make sense in this context.

Comment: Are you sure you use MySQL? That looks more like a MS SQL Server query.

Comment: it's sqlserver not mysql right ?

Comment: MySQL does not support `TOP`. this looks like SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your query returning the wanted 4 rows up in a derived table, then do the opposite `ORDER BY` to get the wanted order:

```
select *
from
(
    select top 4 * from filename where Set=100 order by columname DESC
) dt
order by columname ASC
```

Comment: above command is working But need command explaination. how does dt works. meaning of dt

Comment: The derived table (sub-query named dt) returns the 4 rows with the highest columnvalues. After that apply the presentation order by.